# How can i get the content of a subview in a UiScrollview

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollview in a tab, i added some UIView (NIB) to the UIScrollview. Each UIView has some UISwictch, labels, buttons, etc. How can i get the the label.text inside of the view added to the UIScrollview.

I tried a lot of things but i can access to the content of the UIView added to the UIScrollview.

Comment: Just make a reference to the UIScrollView (@property, iVar, global var) and -addSubview.  No need for the for-loop nonsense.

Comment: I completely agree with @CodaFi , there is no need for that for-loop stuff, especially since the OP doesn't know how to reference the UIView (it's more important to learn how to do that than to simply have code that works)...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check with this,

```
for (UIView *addedView in [self.scrollView subviews])
{
        for (UIView *sub in [addedView subviews])
        {
            if([sub isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
            {
                UILabel *myLabel = (UILabel *)sub;
                NSLog(@"My label :%@",myLabel .text);
            }
        }
}
```

Here `scrollView`  is your scroll view. It will print all label's text.

If you need to print any particular label's text. Then add a tag to it and check the tag before printing it, like `if(myLabel.tag == 7)`

Answer (score 5):

set a unique `tag` for your label.

eg: `label.tag = 10345` (some random number, which is a unique tag)

and you can search for the label in the `parentView` like this

```
UILabel *theLabel = (UILabel *)[parentView viewWithTag: 10345];
```

and then you can do what ever you want with the Label.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Add this code in your scrollview

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTap:)];
singleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
singleTapGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
singleTapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
[scrollView addGestureRecognizer:singleTapGestureRecognizer];
```

Step 2: Implement this method

```
-(void)singleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
 {
    // Convert gesture into view for getting subviews
    CGPoint point = [gesture locationInView:mainScrollView];
    UIView *tappedView = [mainScrollView hitTest:point withEvent:nil];

    // Get the subviews of the view
    NSArray *subviews = [view tappedView];

    // Return if there are no subviews
    if ([subviews count] == 0) return;

    for (UIView *subview in subviews) {

        NSLog(@"%@", subview);

        // List the subviews of subview
        [self your_method:subview];
    }
}
```